# how to use axios get request with proxy without adding to the existing url?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am trying to do a get request with react and axios.
i have a proxy configured in the packages.json
i am using and changing the website url accordin to the buttons clicked. 
and when at last i am trying to do a get request with axios, its not using the proxy as usual but just adds the get url to the existing one in the browser.

any idea what is missing? or wrong?

```
package.json:

...

"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

...
```

the code:

```
export const createUserIfNotExists = user => dispatch => {
  axios.get(`api/user/${user.id}`).then(res => {  // => dispatch => 
    console.log('in createUserIfNotExists response')

...
```

if the url in my site is for example: "https://localhost:3000/search/asd/2/3/asdas" , then it just sends a get request to "https://localhost:3000/search/asd/2/3/api/user/10216805034506570"
instead of 
"https://localhost:3000/api/user/10216805034506570"

i want to use axios as before, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a '/' in the url.

Try with  `axios.get(/api/user/${user.id}` instead of  `axios.get(api/user/${user.id}`